# Jquery modal windows and edit object

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create some modal windows to appear whenever the user wants to edit the object. I haven't done this before, and I've looked for tutorials, but instead of getting some straight forward answers, all I got is more confused! There seem to be sooo many libraries one can use.

So I guess this question is in two parts. If I wanted to do this, are there any particular reasons why I would want to choose Jquery over prototype? Are there more options?

Second part is actually doing it, at this point i don't really care using which library.

I have the following, standard crud, edit and update actions. Now, what I would like is when the user clicks edit, instead of going to the page, pop up a window where he can edit the name of the ticket (this is the only attribute for now).

in the controller I have this:

```
def edit
  @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
  if @ticket.update_attributes(params[:ticket])
    redirect_to tickets_url, :notice  => "Successfully updated ticket."
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

Can anyone please help me with this? Also of course advice and links are more than welcome!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### UPDATE: Here is a Rails 5 Adaptation of this answer using CoffeeScript: https://gist.github.com/1456815

---

jQuery is more popular for good reasons that I won't go into. Plenty on that elsewhere.

Assuming you want to use jQuery, the setup is pretty straightforward:

```
# add the following to your Gemfile under `group :development`
gem 'jquery-rails'

# run the following
$ bundle

# then let the generator install
$ rails g jquery:install
```

And then update your Application.rb javascript expansion defaults:

```
# JavaScript files you want as :defaults (application.js is always included).
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w( jquery rails )
```

And make sure your layout file (e.g. application.html.erb) is including those files:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

---

For your modal, there are a lot of opinions on how to do it. Personally I prefer to roll my own modal windows based on the needs of the application. It's only a few lines of jQuery-laced JS to build modals that work really well with Rails.js:

```
# in a view, perhaps a _modal.html.erb partial that is included into 
# your layout (probably at the bottom).
<div id="modal-container"></div>
<div id="modal">
  <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
</div>
```

Here are some styles (scss style) for the modal that I use:

```
#modal-container {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#modal {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: (-600px - 40px) / 2;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 5px solid #eee;

  & > .close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    color: #666;
    &:hover, &:active {
      color: #000;
    }
  }
}
```

That gets the styles/views out of the way. You might want to customize those styles to fit your application better, but they're pretty generic so they should work to start.

To get it integrated into Rails, there are 2 parts. First, you need to get the browser to send AJAX requests for content and show the modal on return. Second, you need Rails to respond with an appropriate response.

Sending AJAX and handling the responses entails using `:remote => true` on the links/forms you want to be sent remotely.

```
<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path, :remote => true %>
```

That'll create a data attribute on the link that Rails.js will pickup, allowing it to be submitted remotely automatically. It expects a javascript return, and it'll execute that response when it gets it. You can add a quick `format.js` to each actions `respond_to` block, and create an accompanying `new.js.erb` file that contains the JS needed to actually fill in and show the modal. That's okay, but we can DRY it up a bit more than that by returning the template without a layout and moving the modal showing/hiding responsibilities into application.js:

```
# in your app controller, you'll want to set the layout to nil for XHR (ajax) requests
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout Proc.new { |controller| controller.request.xhr? ? nil : 'application' }
end
```

The javascript to make the whole thing work:

```
# in application.js
$(function(){
  var $modal = $('#modal'),
      $modal_close = $modal.find('.close'),
      $modal_container = $('#modal-container');

  # This bit can be confusing. Since Rails.js sends an accept header asking for
  # javascript, but we want it to return HTML, we need to override this instead.
  $('a[data-remote]').live('ajax:beforeSend', function(e, xhr, settings){
    xhr.setRequestHeader('accept', '*/*;q=0.5, text/html, ' + settings.accepts.html);
  });

  # Handle modal links with the data-remote attribute
  $('a[data-remote]').live('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status){
    $modal
      .html(data)
      .prepend($modal_close)
      .css('top', $(window).scrollTop() + 40)
      .show();
    $modal_container.show();
  });

  # Hide close button click
  $('.close', '#modal').live('click', function(){
    $modal_container.hide();
    $modal.hide();
    return false;
  });
});
```

I've got some logic in there to position the modal window 40px from the current scroll position of the browser.

With all of these pieces in place, when you click on a link/form with a remote attribute set, Rails.js will handle submitting the request, your application will know to return just the template for the action without the layout, perfect for displaying it in a modal window, and then our javascript above will hook into the ajax:success callback from Rails.js and display the modal with the template HTML returned from our application.

---

There's more than one way to skin a cat, and more than a dozen ways of building this functionality. This is definitely an area that stronger conventions have yet to be set by the Rails team. This is merely my way of handling this that I feel is fairly DRY, requires minimal effort, and is fairly flexible and future-proof. Perhaps one of the areas that someone could probably build on this is to use a modal/lightbox framework that covers more bases and is more feature-rich. And if someone does that, I'd love to see a write up!

Comment: This is perfect! I followed the steps you outlined and works perfectly! I guess I was always confused because I never saw in the code references to the actual controller or action in question. Would this code work as well if I had drop-downs in my forms?

Comment: Actually just tried and it works as well when drop-downs are present. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Coreyward: How do I get the styling for the close button to work? Do you know? Also I'm thinking maybe of using Jquery UI widgets and effects, but when I check the source code on the modal window... well, there isn't any. It just shows me what's in the parent window. Have you had to work with these in the past? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using SASS? The CSS I provided you is in SCSS syntax. The styles for the close button are nested. You can expand them out to regular CSS if you want, but you should really give SASS a run. As far as the jQuery UI modal window, you could surely adapt what I've provided to use that, but like I said I opted to roll my own because it was quicker.

Comment: SPECTACULAR! Added this just like you said and it worked like a charm. No fixing syntax, not changing values because you had bugs...I did exactly what you said and it worked! thank you very much!

Comment: I've got this working fine when the edit is successful, but how do I get error messages to return back to the modal window? I think I would need to make the form in the modal submit via ajax. I've tried adding `remote: true` to the form (I'm using 3.1), but I'm getting a js error and nothing happens (`uncaught exception ReferenceError elem is not defined`)

Comment: @Brenda You're on the right track with the form being remote, but it sounds like you might be running incompatible versions of jQuery and the UJS library. Try updating to make sure you've got the latest UJS (and make sure you aren't using the Prototype version of UJS with jQuery).

Comment: @coreyward Thank you for such a prompt reply. I made sure I'm on the latest jquery-rails (1.0.19), that is where jquery-ujs is, correct? The form is posting and getting the correct response (I can see it in firebug), I think the web page just doesn't know what to do with it. Should there be another block of code in application.js to handle `form[data-remote]` ?

Comment: Adding similar code for `form[data-remote]` is returning the form errors in the modal. But now it doesn't go back to the original page when the edit is successful. I think I'd better go read up some more on ajax...

Answer (score 0):

For reasons on why jquery over prototype, here's a few thoughts.

1. jquery is now the default Js library for rails 3+ and it replaced the prototype/scriptaculous libraries
2. jquery is engineered to be unobtrusive, meaning it doesn't put your JS code inline; you use proper markup in your HTML file and give proper IDs, classes, and tags to your HTML code so that you can "hook" into it with your jquery code in a separate JS file (I'm not sure if prototype is really unobtrusive or not; I've been using jquery for a few years and haven't touched prototype since)
3. jquery is very simple to learn and use. This is somewhat subjective, but I found jquery's syntax to be extremely simple.  Anything you want to do you probably can in jquery.
4. Jquery also has a very extensive plugin base with a large number of contributors.  Makes finding solutions to common problems much easier than writing them all on your own.
5. Jquery also has Jquery UI, which presents a toolbox of graphical elements to use for your interfaces and front-end (they incidentally have a modal widget, which you could use for your original problem).

Just a few thoughts on jquery.  I highly recommend looking into it.  The jquery site (jquery.com) has some excellent basic tutorials to help slide you into it.  And coreyward did an excellent job of explaining the solution.  I do something similar but picked up a few tips myself.