# Using jquery datepicker in modal window

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

Hi I'm creating modal windows using rails 3, jquery and ajax. The idea is in order to edit objects or create new ones, the window pops up, you edit or create whatever you need and that's it.

However I also want to use datepicker from jquery, inside the modal window. Everything works fine and the calendar pops up when I need it... as long as is not in the modal window. The reason seems to be that when the window pops up, and I check the source code... there's nothing, is as if it doesn't exist, it just shows me whatever is behind the window.

Does this make any sense or has anyone come across something similar?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is an issue in the CSS for the datepicker. I remember that I had a similar issue and the dialog box had a higher z-index in the CSS than the datepicker. If you go in to the CSS for the datepicker in jQuery and set the z-index value higher, it should show up in the modal dialog.

UPDATE:

If you go into the CSS file of the theme you are using (jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css is an example) and then go to line 510 you can replace the line with this

```
.ui-datepicker { z-index: 1002; width: 17em; padding: .2em .2em 0; display: none; }
```

Comment: Hi Waffle, thanks for your answer. I have a very big CSS file for the datepicker, as it comes with a lot of the other widgets and stuff. However I didn't manage to find where the z-index for it was. The only place was some IE adjustment made there.

Comment: Updated my answer for hopefully a much more in-depth solution. Sorry it took me a while to answer, had to go back and find it in my own code.

Comment: Hi Waffle, thanks again. I replaced it but still nothing. The way the modal window works in my app, there's a div in the layout called modal. Then in the application.js I have the functions that link to the modal window when this opens. The design is according to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766055/jquery-modal-windows-and-edit-object) but when the modal window opens, and I check the source code, all I see is the underlying original window, no code for the new one, which is what datepicker is waiting for I'm afraid. Have I got this all backwards?

Comment: Ok, so I am not 100% sure how your app works since I have never really used Ruby-on-Rails. The only thing I am thinking of (and tell me if I am looking at this wrong) is that when you click a button (or something) a modal window is supposed to pop up and be populated from an AJAX request and that window is where the datepicker needs to be showing up? I'm just thinking that the AJAX is possibly re-doing the whole modal window and removing the datepicker when it opens. If you  make sure ajax doesn't overwrite it, the datepicker should stay in the window.